# Finding a problem book in algebraic topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question

I simply need book with problems solved with greatest explanation possible. I know about Hatcher and have a great lecturer, so I do not need theory. I need problems solved in detail.

Comment: There are no books like that. Graduate level mathematics textbooks do not give solutions to the problems, because students cannot learn to do research mathematics unless they learn to solve problems themselves.

Comment: You  might also try connecting the "theory" to the problems. Some problems lead you to develop the theory further, some give interesting applications of the theory. But viewing the problems as something wholly separate from the "theory" is problematic (no pun intended...).